# Longitudinal survey data weights

Tags: panel-data, survey, fixed-effects-model, survey-weights

I'm dealing with a longitudinal survey data now. Do we need to use survey sample weights while running panel data models (e.g., Fixed Effects, Random Effects)? In other words, would it be fine if I simply run a FE for longitudinal survey data without using weights?

Thank you!

Comment: This reads like a question about STATA and would therefore be off-topic here.  But there's also some underlying statistical questions. If you can rewrite it to emphasize that, then it will be on topic.

Comment: I took _penal_ to be a typo for _panel_.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks for the suggestion! I rephrased my question and removed the STATA part.

Comment: @NickCox Yes that was a typo - Thanks!